# App store link in MFMessageComposeViewController shows old image

Tags: swift, sms, messaging, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I have added the URL string for my app to the body of the  MFMessageComposeViewController but when I run the app and send a message the image is an old image from the app store. How can I get it to use the current image from the app store.

```
    fileprivate func textMessage() {
    let appURL_Id = "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/simple-password-keeper/id1326895566"
    let canSend = MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()
    if canSend == true {
        let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        messageVC.body = passwordString + "\n\n" + "Sent by Simple Password Keeper" + "\n\n" + appURL_Id
        messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self
        self.present(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        cantSendTextOrEmailAlert(alertTitle: multiUse.alertTitle, alertMessage: multiUse.messageSMS)
    }
}
```

[image]

And it needs to be.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that in iTunes Connect there is an old preview that was not removed.  Look under the View All Sizes Media Manager.[image]